# zsh: command not found: emulator

Tags: android, react-native, zsh

I am trying to run the emulator -list-avds via terminal, but for some reason keep on getting this error.
Here is my .zshrc profile:

```
export N_PREFIX="$HOME/n"; [[ :$PATH: == *":$N_PREFIX/bin:"* ]] || PATH+=":$N_PREFIX/bin"  # Added by n-install (see http://git.io/n-in$ 
 # Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
export PATH=$PATH:/~nativeGuy/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/~nativeGuy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
```

Comment: You should remove `/` before `~`.  `export PATH=$PATH:~nativeGuy/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: @sungyong Why not make your comment into an answer?

Comment: @nativeGuy : Tilde-expansion does not occur within quoted strings, and only at the beginning of a word. You can verify this by doing a `echo :~:`, which does **not** expand to your home directory.

Comment: @nativeGuy : Please remove the _react-native_ tag. Your question is unrelated to react.

Comment: @nativeGuy : If you think that my answer really answers your question, please consider accepting it. Otherwise update your question or comment on my answer to clarify what is missing.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a

```
that_guys_home_dir=~nativeGuy # Do tilde-expansion
PATH=$PATH:$that_guys_home_dir/Library/Android/sdk
```

This allows you to put other people's home directory into the path. Of course, if **you** happen to be *nativeGuy*, you would simpler do a

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
```

Since you are using zsh, a more elegant solution, which obviates you from worrying about the correct way of doing tilde expansion, would be to do a

```
path+=~nativeGuy/Library/Android/sdk
```

This implicitly sets PATH, because `path` and `PATH` are kept in-sync.